# Resources for repairing double swing door (center pin style)

Tags: doors, hinges

My Google skills have failed me in my task today - I have a double swing cafe-style door between my living room and kitchen that the top pin has become loose on - it appears to me the door is sitting low overall, as it also drags slightly at the threshold.

Alas, I don't actually know what this style of hinge is called, other than it is not the widely-available spring load saloon style I am familiar with - but, It's really kind of a nice door, and I'd love it to work again.

Images of the door, and the top and bottom hinges (click to enlarge):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Anybody got a nice video somewhere of how to adjust, or even assemble/disassemble these? Thanks!

Comment: Search terms;  Pivot hinge, two way swinging door pivot hinge,  Gravity Cafe pivot set,  - https://www.mcmaster.com/swing-hinges/two-way-swinging-door-pivot-hinges/ - https://www.hardwaresource.com/door/pivot-hinges-full-size-doors - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=+vintage+Gravity+Cafe+pivot+set+

Comment: @AlaskaMan - money.  Specifically, https://www.hardwaresource.com/medium-duty-adjustable-spring-pivot-set.html - tech drawing confirmed what I suspected, no height adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to pry down this circular plate and the door will be released.

Shove a screwdriver in there or a spackle knife. You'll want to support the door as upright as possible when doing this because the lateral force on the pin is immense.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  As in my comment on the original question, there is no height adjustment at all in the hinge assembly. - popped the top, shimmed the bottom plate up about 1/8", and reseated that pin and drove some screws.  Thanks.

Comment: @J.T.Sage I was under the impression that you weren't able to get the door off the hinge because of the 3 pictures showing the door still attached so I figured I would show that and you could assess if it's adjustable. You could also consider installing a modern double-action hinge https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-in-x-3-in-Satin-Nickel-Double-Action-Spring-Door-Hinge-14971/202520421

Comment: heh.  briefly considered that.  the downside is the door edges are rounded.  it's a nice detail, but it would make mounting those saloon style's a bit of a challenge (i work in the preforming arts - I've used those saloon's more times than I'd like to count - and nice job linking the good ones.  Lowes has a similar product where the pins are concealed, and they fail *fast*)

Comment: @J.T.Sage Well shimming the bottom plate 1/8" is an acceptable band-aide fix but the same issue will creep up over time until the hinge is ripped out the the door one unsuspecting day. Ideally you would either plane down that edge to be flat or use a tablesaw and install a more robust hinge but if that's not something you're interested in then take solace in knowing that you fixed it (for now) :)

Comment: Aye, eventually I'll need to do more.  Probably at the same time I do something about the floor in there.  Everything else in the house was hardwood in excellent shape (former owner loved her wall-to-wall shag carpet). The kitchen has *at least* 2 layers of linoleum down, one of which is the stuff that had the padded backing.  I've been putting that off for a while.  Thanks again, marking this as answered.

Comment: @J.T.Sage With older homes "eventually" creeps up on you when you least suspect it! Plan it out or else you will have an "immediately" issue at some point :)